# EntityManager.flush() not updating

Tags: java, jpa

I created a Entity class called Role and tried to update a record in the Role table but the flush() method is not updating the record.

Here is the method that it performing the update:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void updateRole(long appUserId, long roleId){
    EntityManager em=getEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Role> query = em.createNamedQuery("Role.findRoleByUser", Role.class);
    query.setParameter("applicationUserId", appUserId);
    Role userRole= query.getSingleResult();
    userRole.setRoleId(roleId);
    em.merge(userRole);
    em.flush();
    em.detach(userRole);
    }
```

Need help in finding the issue.

**Update-1:**
Role.java:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ROLE")
    @NamedQueries({
            @NamedQuery(name = "Role.findRoleByUser",
                    query = "select r from Role r where r.userId = :applicationUserId")
    })
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Role extends AuditInfo{

        public static final Long SYSTEM_USERID = 1000L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
        private long roleId;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private long userId;


        public long getRoleId(){ return this.roleId; }

        public void setRoleId(long roleId) { this.roleId = roleId; }

        public long getUserId() { return this.userId; }

        public void setUserId(long userId) { this.userId = userId; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the mapping of role. Btw you don't need to call merge() flush() and detach() because it will do it automatically. Merge because you are reading the role using a query within a transaction and flush and detach because the persistence context is bound to the transaction.

Comment: @72Services updated the question with Role class

Comment: You can't update the primary key. is it also a primary key on the database? Because a primary key cannot have nullable fields.

Comment: @72Services userId and roleId are foreign keys from two other tables.

Comment: @72Services I got it working. I removed the Primary Key annotation.